# Show debug_message from VcPkg

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

In <VCPKG_ROOT>\scripts\cmake\vcpkg_fixup_pkgconfig.cmake, we have a lot of debug_message(...), but I cannot seem to find where the messages are actually logged, or how do I get the messages to log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set(PORT_DEBUG ON)` shows the messages in the console. Just set in the `portfile.cmake` you want to debug or set it globally in the triplet file you are using.